# Why only first SELECT gets executed?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am working in a simple MySQLi function for `SELECT|INSERT|UPDATE` some table but I can't get it to work. This is the code of the function:

```
function syncReps($fileName, $server, $user, $pass, $db)
{
    $conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        trigger_error('Database connection failed: '.$conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    $data = convertCsvToArray($fileName);
    echo "DEBUG count(data): ", count($data), "\n";

    // Processing on each row of data
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $sql = 'SELECT id,lastSyncAt FROM reps WHERE veeva_rep_id = '.$row['Id'];
        echo "DEBUG: ", $sql, "\n";
        $rs = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($rs === false) {
            trigger_error('Wrong SQL: '.$sql.' Error: '.$conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
        } else {
            $rows_returned = $rs->num_rows;
            $veeva_rep_id = "'".$conn->real_escape_string($row['Id'])."'";
            $first = "'".$conn->real_escape_string(ucfirst(strtolower($row['FirstName'])))."'";
            $last = "'".$conn->real_escape_string(ucfirst(strtolower($row['LastName'])))."'";
            $email = "'".$conn->real_escape_string($row['Email'])."'";
            $username = "'".$conn->real_escape_string($row['Username'])."'";
            $display_name = "'".$conn->real_escape_string(
                    ucfirst(strtolower($row['FirstName'])).' '.ucfirst(strtolower($row['LastName']))
                )."'";

            if ($rows_returned === 0) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO reps(veeva_rep_id,first,last,email,username,lastLoginAt,lastSyncAt,display_name,rep_type,avatar_url) VALUES($veeva_rep_id,$first,$last,$email,$username,NOW(),NOW(),$display_name,'VEEVA','default_avatar.png')";
                echo "DEBUG: ", $sql, "\n";
                $conn->query($sql);
            } else {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute the script from CLI as `php script.php` I got this:

```
DEBUG count(data): 1454
DEBUG: SELECT id,lastSyncAt FROM reps WHERE veeva_rep_id = 00580000008ReolAAC
```

And it's stop at first `SELECT` query, why? if `$data` counts is 1454 shouldn't be executed the same `SELECT` and `INSERT` if `$num_rows === 0`? What I am missing here?

**EDIT**

I am still having a similar issue with another function, see below:

```
function syncTerritories($fileName, $server, $user, $pass, $db)
{
    $conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        trigger_error('Database connection failed: '.$conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    $data = convertCsvToArray($fileName);
    echo "DEBUG count(data): ", count($data), "\n";

    // Processing on each row of data
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM territories WHERE veeva_territory_id='{$row['Id']}'";
        echo "DEBUG: ", $sql, "\n";
        $rs = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($rs === false) {
            echo 'Wrong SQL: '.$sql.' Error: '.$conn->error, E_USER_ERROR;
        } else {
            $rows_returned = $rs->num_rows;

            $veeva_territory_id = "'".$conn->real_escape_string($row['Id'])."'";
            $name = "'".$conn->real_escape_string($row['Name'])."'";

            if ($rows_returned === 0) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO territories(veeva_territory_id,territory_name,createdAt,updatedAt) VALUES($veeva_territory_id,$name,NOW(),NOW())";
                echo "DEBUG: ", $sql, "\n";
                $rs = $conn->query($sql);

                if ($rs === false) {
                    echo 'Wrong SQL: '.$sql.' Error: '.$conn->error, E_USER_ERROR;
                }

                $rs->free();
            } else {
                // UPDATE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is as below:

```
DEBUG count(data): 6911
DEBUG: SELECT id FROM territories WHERE veeva_territory_id='04T800000008zy9EAA'
DEBUG: SELECT id FROM territories WHERE veeva_territory_id='04T80000000903eEAA'
DEBUG: SELECT id FROM territories WHERE veeva_territory_id='04T80000000TOTIEA4'
DEBUG: INSERT INTO territories(veeva_territory_id,territory_name,createdAt,updatedAt) VALUES('04T80000000TOTIEA4','AKORN_101TM',NOW(),NOW())
```

What is wrong now? Should be good move from this way to prepared statements? If so can any give me some query based on mine just as an example?

Comment: veeva_rep_id is a string, so quotes are required in the select wuerry

Comment: I guess `trigger_error` doesn't log to console - the SQL query looks like it will fail because of missing quotes for the ID.

Comment: Just use `$sql = "SELECT id,lastSyncAt FROM reps WHERE veeva_rep_id = '$row[Id]'";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an invalid SQL string to execute. You need to wrap the `veeva_rep_id` value in single quotes:

```
$sql = "SELECT id,lastSyncAt FROM reps WHERE veeva_rep_id='{$row['Id']}'";
```

Comment: or double and save the crazy quotes

Comment: Can you take a look to my edit? I am don't know what is going wrong and I re-check the code several times, can you give me some advice? Again ....